# SSRS LocalReport Mode takes a long time to Render in PDF

Tags: reporting-services

I have a web application that needs to display a number of reports in PDF.  It is an asp.net application and I am using the SSRS LocalReport object to Render in PDF and then writing to the page. I have to use the local mode ( instead of the remote mode ) as I do a lot of processing on the data in C# before sending to the report for rendering.

I have found that these report are taking a long time to render - some over a couple of minutes. This is unacceptable as the previous application, which I also wrote in 2000 using Crystal Reports  V8,is rendering these report in a couple of seconds.

I am using VS 2012, and the report Viewer 2012, and I am amazed that technology has regressed so much in 12 years.

I have notice that SSRS has tremendous problems with page rendering in general and I think it is because the structure of SSRS is control based as opposed to Crystal Reports that is really page based.  So Crystal does not stuggle as much with regards to page sizing , headers , footer and page numbering.

Anyone with a similar problem and any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I have done a lot of research and experimentation and was able to speed the reports up significantly. I would like to share some improvement I implemented.

1.)  Do not use the global total number of pages as it forces the report to be processed twice.

2.)  Avoid using expressions when allocating data to fields.  I found this the leading contributor to the delays.  Some of the expression I was using ...

```
                  = Format(myDate, "dd-MMM-yy")
                  = ": " + myfield.value
```

I did all the formatting in code and fed the formatted data to the report and did not let the report do any expression processing.

3.)   The document map should just be a field and do not use any expressions.

4.)   Set Textboxes  CanGrow property to false where possible.

5.)   Avoid using the code section in the report.

I hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Awesome investigation! My problem was that PDF was slow comparing to XLSX (in several times). 4th item from your list (CanGrow property or if using a UI editor - right click on every field --> Text Box Properties --> Deselect "Allow height to increase") did the whole job, it aligned performance between PDF and XLSX.

Answer (score 0):

Reporting Services has a Report level property called "InteractiveSize". This can be set to 0,0 which basically means the entire report gets rendered on screen. Setting this to an appropriate A4 (21cm,29.7cm)  or other standard page size e.g. US Letter (21.6cm,27.9cm) will cause the report renderer to render pages on demand, the same way Crystal does it.

Comment: Thanks Davos,

Unfortunately I am rendering in PDF and not through the Report Viewer.  Rendering in PDF, actually forces the report pages to be formatted and so the interactive measurement are not used and have no effect on the rendering speed when rendering in PDF.